# How to change Permalinks only for Blogposts

Tags: posts, permalinks

I would like to customize the permalink for all blog posts. Right now they are the same as pages so like this: https://url.com/blogpost

However, I would like to customize the permalink structure for blog posts like this: https://url.com/blog/blogpost

Pages as well as custom posttypes and everything else should not be affected.

Also, is there a clean way to make the 301 links automated and reliable for this change?

Answer (score 1):

Review information here for changing permalinks: [Setting Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/)

Look at Custom Structure and adding /blogpost/%postname%/

For custom post type permalinks you have to disable "with front" so they will not be appended with your custom structure.

For automated redirects and monitoring take a look at this plugin: [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)